# is about iOS 13 update

Tags: ios

After updating to iOS 13 ,For accessing wifi information ,enabled the location service and got the ssid and password but the OS automatically  disconnect from it unknowingly, loss the network connection.

get error XPC connection interrupted

Comment: Hi Dimble, its unclear what your actual question is here. Sounds like you're having some sort of network connection issue, please clarify what it is you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Just reload Simulator. It's a bug.